# how to use a immediate global flag in react function component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Today I found one http request send twice, this is my code look like:

```
 const [isGetUserLoading, setIsGetUserLoading] = useState(false);
 const loadCurrentUser = () => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("userInfo") && isGetUserLoading === false) {
      setIsGetUserLoading(true);
      debugger
      UserService.getCurrUser("/cvpub/user/current-user").then((data: any) => {
        if(ResponseHandler.responseSuccess(data)){
          setUserInfo(data.result);
          localStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data.result));
          setIsGetUserLoading(false);
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

when load current user, I make a global flag that shows the user is loading. when I tracing into the code, I found the setIsGetUserLoading did not change the flag immediately. what should I do to set the global flag to keep the get current user only execute onece?

Comment: Is your `useState()` hook with `isGetUserLoading` your "global flag"? Your debugger line is immediately under `setIsGetUserLoading(true)`. React does not instantly set the `useState()` value after you call the updater function, those updates happen asynchronously at the _end_ of the React render cycle.